# Get first element from array or null using Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an array

```
const arr1 = ["string1", "string2"]
const arr2 = []
```

And I want to get the first element of this array, or null if it is empty.

How can I do this using Ramda?

Comment: FWIW you don't need Ramda for this: `const firstOrNull = arr => arr[0] ?? null`

Comment: I would use `const firstOrNull = ([f = null]) => f`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `R.propOr()` to get a value from an object or array by key/index, and return a default if the result is `undefined`:

```js
const firstOrNull = R.propOr(null, 0)

const arr1 = ["string1", "string2"]
const arr2 = []

console.log(firstOrNull(arr1))
console.log(firstOrNull(arr2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: On Typescript I got the error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' on 0 of propOr

Comment: The problem is with the TS typing mostly. You can circumvent it like this `const firstOrNull = propOr(null, 0 as any)`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `head`. However, it would return undefined rather than null when the list is empty.